# incorrect image size in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, size

I need to use `image height` and `width`.I have `800*800` pixel `image` in my `ios simulator`. But when i am finding the size of `image` using

```
image.size.width and image.size.height
```

it is giving me `315*120` which is incorrect why so?

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info 
{
    NSLog(@"%@",info);

    int temp = [[DataManager sharedObj] imageCount];

    for(NSDictionary *dict in info) 
    {
        [[DataManager sharedObj]  setImageCount:temp+1];

        NSMutableDictionary* dataDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        UIImage* img = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        NSLog(@"%.2f",img.size.width);
        NSLog(@"%.2f",img.size.height);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `image.frame = cgrectmake(x, y, 800, 800)`.

If you have an `UIImageView *image` instead of `UIImage *image`, problably you get the frame of the view not the image.

---

**SOLVED:**
change `fullScreenImage` to `fullResolutionImage` in line 33 of your `ELCImagePickerController.m`.

Comment: but i dont know size of each image.so how i can do that.need size of image not frame

Comment: Are you sure that `image` is an `UIImage` and not an `UIImageView` with the frame size of 315*120?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image size by using this

```
UIImage *imageS = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSLog(@"width = %.2f, height = %.2f", imageS.size.width, imageS.size.height);
NSLog(@"Image Size = %@",NSStringFromCGSize(imageS.size));
```

Both lines will work.

It will print right. Please check your simulator image once again. If you added it via google may me you have been saved the image thumbnail instead of original image thats why you are getting the size wrong. Otherwise method of getting image size is correct.